# Should I ask HR about an upcoming "promotion" my manager cannot consistently explain?

Tags: software-industry, career-development, promotion, title

I have been at my current employer for more than five and less than ten years in software engineering roles. I am unquestionably recognized a top performer doing important work, but I would like to have more and greater responsibility, including but not limited to managerial responsibilities.

There was a significant management shakeup at my employer just before the start of the COVID-19 pandemic; we got a new CEO from another company in our industry, who promptly replaced a lot of upper and middle management, including our entire HR department, with people that worked at his previous company. I have changed managers twice during this period. My original manager decided to leave the company after the shakeup. My second manager is still with the company, but he had too much going on under him and had to focus on another area of responsibility after 6 months or so. My third and current manager joined my employer via the CEO's old-boys network; I have been working with him since he started, but only have been reporting to him for about 8 months.

With all of the changes, I haven't had much in the way of clarity regarding my own career development. Making that more complicated, there were no raises or promotions last year, because the pandemic hurt our business. This year, business has improved, so the company has rather loudly announced that it is doing promotions and merit increases. This is the first time it is being done under the New HR People, so there is a new process in place that nobody has practical knowledge of, but it may be similar to what was done at CEO's Previous Company. The company has also rolled out a series of standardized pay levels and titles for roles; one's title is supposed to correspond with one's pay grade.

I have been told by my manager that he has submitted my name for promotion to a managerial position. Upon first hearing this, it sounded like exactly the sort of thing I was interested in. However, I asked some questions to make sure that I understood what was happening, and the answers don't make much sense to me.

It was claimed by my manager that:

- Because it is a promotion, my pay grade will increase by one level (Good)
- I will get a title on the managerial track, rather than the technical track (Good)
- This will be a new type of role that did not exist previously that is intended to be prestigious (Uhh... that's OK I guess? Though I don't really know why?)
- The managerial title the role will have is the one corresponding to one pay grade lower than my current title.
- I cannot have the current_level+1 managerial title because I do not have prior managerial experience.

This inconsistency bothers me because it contradicts HR's explanation of the title and grade system. HR published a table of equivalent titles across tracks, and said that people get the title associated with their grade regardless of which track they are on. There is no published rule about people needing managerial experience anywhere in any policy. Additionally, the company has a long history pre-dating the current crowd, of promoting people from engineering roles into managerial roles in exactly this fashion that I'm now being told is prohibited.

I had to provide my manager with the table showing the two career tracks and titles from an HR presentation; he was not aware of the level and title discrepancy. Regardless, he keeps insisting that I will ***absolutely not*** get the title indicated by the leveling system. When I point out that there are three other people who made similar transitions with no management experience, he simply repeats I will not be getting that title. When I ask what that means for my pay grade, he simply says that I'll get "a bump" and "we'll figure all of that out later." The "bump" is not quantified (pending financial approval) and "later" is not defined either, but the process is supposed to be finalized early next year.

The title itself doesn't matter much to me, but because everything I'm being told is contradictory, I can't answer a simple question like whether this is really a promotion or not. I also don't really have clarity on what is actually happening now.  And because the promotion process is still going on, I do not know whether it is appropriate or useful to ask more questions. It seems like my manager isn't going to give me clear answers because he simply does not know and/or doesn't think this is important.

Because this involves a contradiction between what HR has said and what my manager has said, is it appropriate to ask HR for clarity about this? I do not want to "snitch" on my manager or do something that jeopardizes whatever it is I'm getting, but I also feel like I'm being subject to treatment I'm not supposed to be, and it's not going to sit right with me until it makes sense, even if it is supposed to be something nice.

Comment: Someone has already VTC on the basis that it is a question about seeking advice about a company-specific policy. I am not seeking advice about a company-specific policy from Workplace.SE; I'm seeing advice about whether seeking advice from my company HR in this case is wise.

Comment: Why not wait until the promotion is given to find out more? It's nice to have clarity earlier, but would knowing more now be actionable in any way for you?

Comment: @MichaelMcFarlane If the "promotion" is not at all what it is cracked up to be, or if the new management is just erecting new flaming loops to make me jump through that other people haven't had to before, I'd probably prefer to work elsewhere.

Comment: I do not believe HR would comment on any decisions that are either not finalized or were not formally announced.

Comment: @PM77-1 I don't want HR to comment on a *decision.* I want HR to explain *processes* that are used to make the decision.

Comment: It sounds like the process is being extracted from HR/Management's fundament-als.  With the largescale leadership turnover I suspect no one is entirely sure how it is supposed to work at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what he is telling you is

1. You are getting a pay raise
2. You are being put on a management track, as you want
3. Traditionally, someone has to enter into management at your new
   level so that has to be your level/title
4. Traditionally, someone at that level actually gets paid less than
   you currently do, but the normal pay grade that would correspond to
   your current and soon-enhanced rates, that they feel you deserve and have
   earned, are only available to those who already have management experience and
   are in a higher-level position, which they can't give you because of the
   experience requirement
5. So, basically, they're starting you at two pay levels higher than
   someone usually starting out at a position with your new title.

It sounds like you are being given everything you said you wanted, and they are going out of their way to make an exception to the standard/usual protocols to make that happen for you.

If the inconsistency in title bothers you, please understand that you are not qualified and do not meet the baseline requirements for the higher level title. The inconsistency is that they are paying you two pay levels above what someone starting at that position would normally make. So, perhaps, you should take a glass-half-full view and be pleased about this particular inconsistency. Sounds like they fully expect you to move up to the titles that will eventually align with your compensation and range of duties, which is much better than your value being lost in the shuffle of top, upper and middle management changes.

I would not suggest going to HR and raising an issue about this, because it might come off as complaining about them making an exception to accommodate compensating you for what you are worth while also allowing you to get onto the career track that you desire.

Comment: "Traditionally, someone has to enter into management at your new level" Umm, no, that's the source of the dispute right there. "Traditionally", meaning in the history of the company, this was not the case, and people just as "unqualified" as I am have not had to enter at this level (which did not even exist at the company until this year).

Comment: @Joe - CEO is bringing in management and folks who were with him, previously, right? Policies and structure are all coming in from this same CEO, right?  So, while "traditionally" might be the wrong word for your company, as it applies to how this CEO structures and runs things, it applies.  So you're saying that people with zero management experience have been made managers at that higher level UNDER THE NEW MANAGEMENT? Sounds like you're generally unhappy with the changes. Fair enough, but complaining about THAT will get you nowhere. They have given you everything you claim you wanted.

Comment: @Joe - Let's put it this way: the explanation you were given seemed very clear to me, an outsider. Your follow-up comment, along with the question, seems to suggest that you're unhappy with how the company has changed, you see it as the CEO basically brining in cronies and buddies and running roughshod over everything you built in your career. You frame it as illogical madness run amok because that is what you WANT it to be viewed as, to justify your own dissatisfaction. What they were saying, despite it not being what you want, seems pretty clear. Belaboring that will probably not  help you.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet, you're overlooking the more obvious explanation which is that the new management are simply attacking the workforce, and changing the promotion practices that were previously well-known (including that those with no management experience, were given a particular management title and pay grade as part of their development into that role). There's nothing Illogical about having earlier committed to a particular company partly because of its future prospects and its established practices around career development, and to be aggrieved when those prospects are changed.

Comment: @Steve - How is putting someone on the career track they want, giving them the pay raise they want, and making an exception to the "template" the company wants to follow by giving them a two-step above standard pay rate for that position "attacking" OP? They are literally giving him everything he says he wants, but in the process of making this exception, he can't get the title that normally matches the pay rate until a later point. You can look at it as "I want the title that usually matches that pay," or you can look at it as "you're getting more pay for that position you are in than usual."

Comment: @Steve - If OP has issues with how the management overhaul is being done, and the changes made are being carried out, that can very well be legitimate. But claiming that not having this position title, when they state they have a specific criteria for that position title, that OP does not meet, is not an indication of any other issues that OP might have with what is going on. I'm not overlooking anything. OP isn't asking about any of the other stuff. He's asking about this, when his issue is, obviously, with everything else that is going on.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet, you know the answer to your own question. The terms offered to the OP are inferior to the established practice. That's all there is to it. It's immaterial that it involves a payrise nevertheless, or puts him the track he wants. It still does not put him in the position that he could previously have expected, and in that sense it is an attack on the workforce. Also, his manager has been evasive about the payrise - almost certainly, it will be less than he could have expected if he had been given the hitherto customary title for the promotion.

Comment: @Steve - Seems to me that he's getting a pay rate two levels above the established practice for someone starting in the management career track with no prior management experience, so, no, I would say that does not qualify as "inferior."

Comment: @PoloHoleSet, I think we've struck on your misunderstanding. The pay rate is *not* two levels "above the established practice". The pay rate is if anything beneath the established practice, in accordance with a *new* company policy. That's why the OP is annoyed about the situation. The latest declaration by new management is not equivalent to an "established practice", when it contradicts company practices that have been established over many years.

Comment: @Steve - the established practice, according to original post is - starting with the title he is getting for anyone without management experience. That positions standard entry pay is 1 level below his **current** rate. Along with the title in this management track, he is also getting a raise.  So, that is, absolutely 2 levels above the standard rate for someone entering into management without previous management experience.

What previous management did, under a regime that got swept out the door, is irrelevant. OP even says "this will be a new type of role that did not exist previously."

Comment: @PoloHoleSet, unfortunately the practice to which you refer is not the "established" practice, it's the *new* practice. The relevance of what the previous management did, is that it defines the "established practice".

Comment: @Steve - unfortunately, with completely new management, from top to bottom, practices that have been thrown out the door are no longer established practices, either. If they have a stated policy and format they have been following for over a year, that IS "established." This idea that new management is somehow required to try to follow, verbatim, the practices of the group they are replacing is a bit unrealistic and absurd.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet, I'm not saying the new management must abide by established expectations. I'm saying you're misrepresenting or misunderstanding the content of the OP's question by asserting that he's getting everything he wanted. What he wanted was the established career path, and it's quite clear he isn't getting it. I don't believe the OP used the word "established" - that's my word which you are also clearly misunderstanding or misinterpreting.

Comment: Of course you are. You are creating this odd scenario where the new management following the policies they put in place over a year ago, when they took over, is considered screwing over OP because it doesn't follow what was done before they arrived. They "established" their new policies when they got the keys, and they are following them. My entire answer is pointing out that going to the **NEW** HR and complaining that getting a raise and entry into the management track, which OP wanted, is unfair because of an **OLD** policy from the **OLD** administration will only cause trouble for OP.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet, a year is not very long if the OP has been there 5-10 years. He said the management changed about a year ago, not that the policy changed a year ago (or that, even if it changed in principle then, that the consequences were obvious to him a year ago). You may be right that the OP won't get anywhere by complaining, but that's not the same as saying he has no complaint (or no legitimate complaint). Resisting attacks by management almost always cause trouble, yet many feel it is trouble that has to be sustained to ensure that they are not attacked even more frequently or brutally.

Comment: @Steve - BEFORE the start of covid, so almost two years, and he said that the new CEO "promptly" cleaned house, including HR. The question isn't "Am I righteous to be hacked off about this?", it is "**SHOULD** I complain to HR?"  You guys act like I'm a cheerleader for the changes.  I'm pointing out that he got everything of substance he said he wanted, except for a specific title, and complaining to HR is only going to ID him as a "problem-child" in their eyes.  If that minutiae bothers him so much that getting put onto a management track and a raise isn't enough, then he should leave.

Comment: @Steve - I didn't say he has no complaint about changes, I said that there was nothing confusing or contradictory in what he was told, but, rather, he just didn't like the message.  And I stand by that.  It is very clear what they are saying, and it doesn't seem to conflict with any CURRENT policies or understandings. He didn't say, at the start "what I really want is the specific title of Chief Senior Widget Planner," he said he wanted to be put onto a management track, and he wanted a compensation bump that was overdue.  He got both of those, and now he's complaining about what it's called.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet, again you just don't seem to be reading his plain words. You say "there was nothing confusing or contradictory". He says "The 'bump' [in salary] is not quantified (pending financial approval) and 'later' is not defined either". Usually when management don't tell you how much a proposed raise is, nor when it will arrive, that is not only "confusing", but a sign of bad faith when accompanied by other explicit attacks (such as on the title he would customarily receive).